# flask fill the form with values from python dict

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I want the flask form to pre-populate the data from python dict

The function form_input() gets python dict 'ext'and return form.

The error i am getting is "jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'str object' has no attribute 'issuer'"

```
@app.route('/form_input', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def form_input():

ext = session['ext']
if request.method == 'POST':
    form  = Dataentryform(request.form, obj=ext)    


return render_template("inputdata.html",form='form')
```

Ext being Python dict -

```
([('amount', 200.22), ('currency', 'USD'), ('date', datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 30, 0, 0)), ('desc', 'Invoice from KOTH Commercial Broker'), ('invoice_number', ('DTBINT', '0907')), ('issuer', 'KOTH Commercial Broker'), ('partner_name', 'KOTH Commercial Broker')])
```

Here is input.html

```
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
<form method=post>
<dl>
    {{ render_field(form.issuer) }}
    {{ render_field(form.invoice_number) }}
    {{ render_field(form.date) }}
    {{ render_field(form.currency) }}
    {{ render_field(form.amount) }}
</dl>
<p><input type=submit value=Submit>
```

Answer (score 0):

`form` should be a variable and not a string.

So change

`return render_template("inputdata.html",form='form')`

to

`return render_template("inputdata.html",form=form)`